# jQuery Remove part of the HTML and append new HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

We have approval with our client, just a heads up to cover me in any way.

We are needing to modify some of the code in a clients site if a cookie is seen on their computer, the client's site is in ASPX format.  I have the first part of the code created, but where I am getting stuck is this:

I need to remove the last 2000 characters (or so) of the body of the page, then append the new HTML to it.

I tried:

```
$('body').html().substring(0, 10050)
```

but that doesn't work, I also tried copying that HTML (which did work) and put it back with the new code, but it created a loop of the script running.

Any suggestions on what I should do?  It has to be javascript/jQuery sadly.

//////// EDIT ////////////

My script is brought in by Google Tag Manager, and added to the page at the bottom, then my script runs, this is what was causing the loop in the script.  Basically, here is the setup:

My Script on my server is loaded into the client site using Google Tag Manager, added to the bottom of the page.  From there it is able to execute, but when doing this, it creates a loop of adding the Google Tag Manager script, causing my code to re-add, causing it to re-execute again.

The client is not willing to do anything, he has pretty much told us to just figure it out, and to not involve his web guy.

This is the code straight from their site I am trying to edit.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
jQuery(function($){
$('#txtPhone').mask('(999) 999-9999? x99999');
$('#submit').click(function(){CheckForm();});
});
function CheckForm(theForm){  
if (!validRequired($('#txtfirst_name'),'First Name')){ return false; } 
if (!validRequired($('#txtlast_name'),'Last Name')){ return false; }
if (!validRequired($('#txtEmail'),'E-Mail Address')){ return false; } 
if (!validEmail($('#txtEmail'),'E-Mail Address',true)){ return false; }
if (!validPhone($('#txtPhone'),'Phone Number')){ return false; }

var dataList='fa=create_lead';
dataList += '&name=' + $('#txtfirst_name').val();
dataList += '&lastname=' +$('#txtlast_name').val();
dataList += '&email=' + $('#txtEmail').val();
dataList += '&phone=' + $('#txtPhone').val();

dataList += '&vid=' + dealerOnPoiVisitId;
dataList += '&cid=' + dealerOnPoiClientId;
dataList += '&leadType=9';
dataList += '&leadSrc=32'; ////////////////////// THIS IS WHAT I AM ATTEMPTING TO CHANGE /////////////////////////
dataList += '&contactname=' + $('#contactname').val();
dataList += '&comment=' + encodeURIComponent($('#txtComments').val());
dataList += '&dvc=' +encodeURIComponent(DealerOn_Base64.encode($('#txtfirst_name').val() + $('#txtEmail').val()));
var lid=1;
$('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
 $.ajax({
url:'/lead.aspx',
data: dataList,
dataType: 'json',
success: function(data){
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
lid=data.leadid;
if (lid > 1){
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
var jqxhr = $.post('/lead.aspx?fa=complete_lead&leadid=' + lid , function() {
window.location.href='/thankyou.aspx?name=' + $('#txtfirst_name').val() + '&lid=' + data.leadid;
});
}
},
error: function(request,error) {
$('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
}
}); 
}
</script>
```

This is the page on the site: www.moremazda.com/contactus.aspx

Comment: Is there only text in the `body`? If there are also HTML elements in there, how are you planning on making sure that you are left with valid HTML after removing the last 2000 characters?

Comment: I am basically needing to modify just a single line of the code in a JS snippet toward the bottom of their site (it is in the last 2000 characters of the `body`, I copied the HTML, and recreated it to work with the `$('body').append();` command in jQuery.  If I am able to search the <script> tag for that specific line of code, and modify it, that would be 1000x easier.

Comment: Tell us exactly what you're trying to do, and maybe we'll think of something really smart !

Comment: If you are only trying to target a specific element, don't try to change the body.

Comment: Not sure I get it, are you adding Tag Manager from your script, which in turn adds your script, which adds Tag Manager, which ....

Comment: Well hmm `Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined contactus.aspx:242
ajax-in jquery dealeron.js:245
77194037 dealeron.js:250
ajax-done jquery ` on the linked page

Comment: mark - That would be someone elses' code. :) Not mine, if mine were causing an error, it would be repeating and be moremazda.js not dealeron.js

adeneo - Tag Manager is a thing where I can put in almost anything, and have it execute through one line of code. Google tag manager is installed onto the client site, and I am loading my JS through Google Tag Manager, when I copy the HTML, cut off the last 2000 characters, and paste it back with the new ending, it re-adds Google Tag Manager, which re-adds my script, which executes again doing the same thing.

Comment: SO< you want to change just the one line, or the rest of the "script" element or just the text inside that single quote? Really, that page has multiple jQuery versions on it.

Comment: Mark, that is the thing I don't like about the site, the creators put so much stuff on it, I wish they would redo it, but they won't.  I am using the pre-existing Jquery on the site.

Comment: You realize that once that script tag is parsed and executed, changing it won't make a difference as it's already executed. It's not like DOM elements where the change is visible once you remove an element ?

Comment: The script is going to post to a url on the click of a button, I am going to change the script before the user clicks the button on the contact form, so we are able to claim the source as ours when it is, and when it is not, it is theirs.

Comment: But once the event handler that handles that click is loaded into memory, changing the text inside the script tag will do nothing ?

Comment: As @adeneo points out, you need to remove the click handler, NOT the javascript.

Comment: Well then, sounds like I am out of luck. Well, ok! That sucks though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the HTML back:

```
var html = $('body').html().substring(0, 10050);
$('body').html(html);
```

Note that doing this, and just randomly removing chunks of HTML is not good practice, and could lead to a number of problems.

Comment: The problem with that is it created a loop of doing it, causing the page to crash.

Comment: Then you're doing something else wrong, as this doesn't create a loop, just a shitload of other problems.

Comment: It is more complicated than what I explained, that is my bad. I am editing the post now.

Comment: It's like saying "I want a shorter car, can you cut the last 15 inches in the back?"

Answer (score 0):

Technically you should be able to do this:

```
var bodyHTML = $('body');
bodyHTML.html(bodyHTML.html().substring(2000));
```

But as I pointed out in my comment above, that is a REALLY BAD idea.

If you have access to the HTML to the page, wrap the code you want to replace in a identifiable tag and remove that.  I.e.:

```
<div id="tobeRemoved">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<script>
    $('#toBeRemoved').empty();
</script>
```

If you can't edit the HTML, but you know that it is always the last `script` tag, you could do something like this:

```
var scripts = $('script');
scripts.get(-1).remove;
```